# Parsing XML data while using SQLXML to Bulk Load into database

Tags: .net, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, xml-parsing, sqlxml

I have an XML file that I would like to load into a relational database (SQL Server 2008 R2) using .NET (I can choose any framework). I understand the easiest way to do that is via the [SQLXML Bulk Loader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171878.aspx).

Using the bulk loader, is it possible to parse the XML data from a single element, into multiple columns.

For example, given:

```
<vuln:product>cpe:/a:magpierss:7.1</vuln:product>
```

Can the XML be parsed, such that "magpierss" ends up in one database table column and "7.1" goes in another column?

Secondly, some elements have a limited set of values (enumerations).

For example

```
<favoriteColor>red</favoriteColor>
<favoriteColor>blue</favoriteColor>
```

Id like to replace said element data with the enumeration values I've defined in a different database table (i.e. "Red" -> 0, "Blue" -> 1 or "Green" -> 2). Rather then loading the actual string values over and over again.

Are either of these two things possible using the SQLXML bulk loader? If not, what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

you can use SQL server XML parsing

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<SampleXML>
 <favoriteColor>
     <favoriteColor>red</favoriteColor>
     <favoriteColor>blue</favoriteColor>
<favoriteColor/>
</SampleXML>'

SELECT
a.b.value(‘favoriteColor[1]/favoriteColor[1]’,‘varchar(10)’) AS Color1,
a.b.value(‘favoriteColor[1]/favoriteColor[1]’,‘varchar(10)’) AS Color2
FROM @MyXML.nodes(‘SampleXML’) a(b)
```

Links :[OpenXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175160.aspx)

[reading-xml-file-using-t-sql](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/13/sql-server-simple-example-of-reading-xml-file-using-t-sql/)

[openxml-xml-integration-with-sql-server](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rekhasingh1610/openxml-xml-integration-with-sql-server/)

[How-to-Traverse-Hierarchical-XML](http://blog.bodurov.com/How-to-Traverse-Hierarchical-XML/)